# When should I buy cities in Age of Wonders I and when should I not?

Tags: age-of-wonders

In Age of Wonders, if you encounter a neutral city of a friendly race, you are offered to either fight the inhabinants normally to take it, or pay them some gold and have them as units.

When should I buy, and when should I fight? What is the list of criteria to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at three criteria in this situation:

- Do I have enough gold to spare? The investment is usually significant. Are there any more important things I can use the gold on?
- Can I make use of the troops? Early game, when my armies are small the extra soldiers from that town could be very helpful. Later on, the soldiers from the town could be a nice town defence, which is immediately available and I don't have to spend the turns producing them.
- Do I need the experience? Is my hero or any of the soldiers close to levelling up? would that help in an immediate fight? Would that help more than the extra soldiers?

Comment: Good answer! You could also note that it is sometimes *very bad* to have low-tier troops later in the game, because they eat your money, but are not as cost-effective as stronger units. At the same time, you can't "fire" them like in some other games, as they will wander the map, attack your units and capture your cities. But early in the game 1-st level troops are your bread and butter.